# How get an ID number and increment it by +1 in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

In a bash script : get an ID number and increment it by +1

The value is at line 4 of the file :
`2019020908   ; sn`

I'm trying the following method :

ID Recovery

```
sn=$(cat *myfile* | grep "; sn" | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
```

2019020908

Increment +1

```
sn1=$(echo $sn | awk '{print $0+1}')
```

2019020909

Change the value

```
sed -i -e 's/$sn/$sn1/g' *myfile*
```

This is where it doesn't work and nothing shows on the stdout. I want to be able to use the result of the two variables to change the value of the ID.

I tried different things with sed but nothing worked. Do you think it comes from the last command or the whole method needs to be reviewed ?

Comment: Why so complicated? Incrementing the number could be simply done by `((sn1=sn+1))`, or, if you don't need the old value anymore, by `((sn+=1))`, which would change `sn` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat file
2019020908   ; sn

$ awk '/; sn/{$1++} 1' file
2019020909 ; sn
```

or if you care about retaining the white space before the `;`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/ *; sn/){$0=$1+1 substr($0,RSTART)} 1' file
2019020909   ; sn
```

If you want to update the input file then:

If you're using GNU awk just change `awk 'script' file` to `awk -i inplace 'script' file`, otherwise with any awk, change it to `tmp=$(mktemp) && awk 'script' file > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" file`.

In addition to being inefficient, here's one way in which the `grep + awk + bash + sed` approach can fail:

```
$ cat myfile
17   ; sn
100.10.10.17   ; ip
```

```
$ sn=$(grep "; sn" myfile | awk -F';' '{print $1}')
$ sn1=$((sn + 1))
$ sed "s/$sn/$sn1/g" myfile
18; sn
100.10.10.18; ip
```

Note that the IP address undesirably changed.

Now try the same with just an awk command:

```
$ awk '/; sn/{$1++} 1' myfile
18 ; sn
100.10.10.17   ; ip
```

Note that the IP address remains unchanged.

Comment: I think `awk '/; sn/{sub($1,$1+1)}1'` retains whitespace

Comment: @jhnc yes it does, you should add that as an answer. I normally wouldn't do that in case of metachars in $1 but there shouldn't be any in this case given the OPs input format,

Answer (score -1):

I succeeded with this method

```
sn=$(grep "; sn" myfile | awk -F';' '{print $1}')
sn1=$((sn + 1))
sed -i "s/$sn/$sn1/g" myfile
```

Comment: Yes I changed, I think it's better that way

Comment: It's still overly complicated and fragile/buggy. It could fail in several different ways depending on the content of your input file.